# Can't run "ruby -v" after install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I followed [this guide](http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-ruby-on-rails-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6/) to install `Ruby` on `Centos 6.5` with `Mod Passenger` and `Apache`. But after running the command: `# curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` and then running `ruby -v` in the console,  I got this message

`-bash: ruby: command not found`

what am I doing wrong? Can any one share a good guide or tutorial to get this working? I need to create a `ROR` application to start programming on this.

Comment: You installed ruby, but you have not loaded it into the shell. RVM is similar to a package manager, but strictly for ruby. You have have multiple different version of ruby installed at any given time. Which means you need to select the version of ruby that you want to actually work with. Read the [documentation](https://rvm.io/) to learn how to properly use it.

Comment: @JustinWood Good answer but I need a little push since I'm doing my first steps with Ruby and RoR, from all the possibilities [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) what's the right I should go on?

Comment: @ReynierPM: The part where it says "Install a version of Ruby"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `/bin/bash --login` to load it to bash shell.

Then run rvm list known to see what all ruby versions are available for download. You could see,

```
$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p545]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p353
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p451]
[ruby-]2.1.1
[ruby-]2.1-head
ruby-head
```

After that just install the ruby version you need using `rvm` command. E.g.,

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.1
```

After having installed multiple ruby versions, run command `rvm list` to see what all ruby versions are installed,

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p371 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Then using the command `rvm use` to use a particular ruby version for a particular project (from inside the project directory only). E.g.,

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1
```

If you want it as the default version (May be you are running most of the ruby projects in ruby-2.1.1 version only), just use the below command,

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1 --default
```

After all that just see the `rvm list`, you could see the versions currently in use and selected by default. Both can also be the same ruby version.

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p371 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Then, just run `ruby -v`, you can see the ruby version selected for the project as,

```
ruby 2.1.1
```

run the command `rvm help` to know about more commands.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

RVM is just a Ruby version manager. It isn't actually Ruby itself. Once you have installed RVM, you need to install some actual Ruby version (e.g. `rvm install 2.1`).